# GLMM and two slopes

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

My outcome variable is binomial, and I have 11 independent variables and a time variable. The time variable has different slopes, so I fixed it to `time-before` and `time-after`. I used the `lme4` package (the `glmer` function).  I have a random intercept and two random slopes. I created my model like this:

```
m3.glmm <- glmer(y ~ timebefore + timeafter + x1 + x2 +...+ x11 +     
(1+timebefore+timeafter|id),
             data = data, family = binomial (link="logit"), nAGQ=3)
```

When I used this model, I had this error:

```
Error in updateGlmerDevfun(devfun, glmod$reTrms, nAGQ = nAGQ) : 
  nAGQ > 1 is only available for models with a single, scalar random-effects term
```

Anyone have a simple explanation of how to fit (or code) this model?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the number of abscissas, or nodes, you've selected for the Adaptive Gaussian Quadrature (AGQ) approximation of the log-likelihood, specified by `nAGQ`.  The default value is 1 (equivalent to the Laplacian approximation).

The `glmer` function's Details section (page 29 in the `lme4` [help page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf)) states:

> The most reliable approximation for GLMMs is adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature, at present implemented only for models with a single scalar random effect.

Limiting the AGQ approximation to single scalar random effects is not a limitation of AGQ, but appears to be a decision made by the `lme4` package writers, as noted [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q4/017099.html) by Douglas Bates back in 2011 (relevant piece quoted below):

> It may seem that this issue could be put to rest by incorporating an
>   adaptive Gauss-Hermite method in glmer ...
>   there has been such a method in versions of glmer but only for very
>   specific models. We will add it but right now we are concentrating on
>   other issues in the development.

So, to get your code to execute, I believe setting `nAGQ` to 1 would work.

Comment: But doing so , that is setting `nAGQ=1` when I have random slope , will give biased estimates specifically for standard error of higher level ?

Comment: And if so will I quit R (  seems `glmer` is  probably best for GLMM in R ) and use another software such as STATA , SAS  ?

Comment: @ABC right; it's definitely a limitation of `glmer`.  From Douglas Bates in the link I provided in my answer:  "In some ways I think that reliable optimization of the approximate log-likelihood is more important and that is an area where R is not strong.  Far too much optimization code is covered by licenses that are not compatible with R's license and the pickings for Open Source optimization code are somewhat slim.  I wish I had access to some of the optimizers that SAS uses but we don't so we make use of what we do have."  Note: I have no concept of how relevant this comment is in 2015.

Comment: I don't know whether SAS does AGQ (i.e. as distinct from Laplace, with >1 quadrature point) for vector-valued random effects.  GLLAMM in Stata definitely does (see http://andrewgelman.com/2010/09/10/r_vs_stata_or_d/). @MikeWierzbicki, your quotation is a little off target; the absence of vector-valued AGQ in `lme4` is not due to lack of optimization code (we now have Steve Johnson's NLOptr to build on), but rather the absence of the appropriate code in https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/99f7be405d33a9d40a86085d14e4c16359ea632a/src/external.cpp (search for `glmerAGQ`) ...

Comment: @BenBolker +1 -- thanks for the clarification!  That's definitely good to know.

Comment: Really an informative answer . +1 .

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/292d7f68dc4bfdfe7405703f730b71983193e5ba/R/lmer.R#L261-L263